# Laptop GPU by Price-performance

Tags: laptop, gaming, graphics-cards

I'm reaching the limits of my old Notebook, since it only has a GeForce 630M and I want to use it for a bit of gaming, too. It's kinda  sad, because the i7-2670QM still does the job quite well...

I'm thinking about buying a new one, but I'd like to have a nice graphics card that does it's job without beeing too expensive. So what is the graphics card (I prefer Nvidia, but if AMD has something way better I would also consider using it) with the best Price-performance ratio?

Requirements:

- Laptop GPU available in normal sized Notebooks (I don't want a monster, it should still be *portable*)
- at least 1 HDMI output
- at least 2 outputs in sum, preferable VGA
- able to be used for games on the market right now (not high settings, just *playable* - my current 630M doesn't even manage 5 FPS for Rise of the Tomb Raider on lowest settings)
- I don't want to spend mroe than 1k€ for the full system (or rather I can't afford T.T), and since I also want an i7 and a good amount of RAM, the GPU itself mustn't be too expensive

If you have suggestions for a full system, this would be nice, too, but the question aims to give me a overview of Graphic Cards which would meet my requirements. Afterwards I'll search for a new Notebook with one of these built in.

---

I just had a quick look into the comparison site suggested by Adrian, an found the GeForce GTX 775M - this would be, from the performance aspect, top notch. I don'T even know how the price range is, and if this is available in non-gaming-notebooks (meaning normal sized cases), but anyway - this performance would be awesome. 
For the lower bound I'd name the GeForce GTX 580M - it shouldn't be much less performance than this, else I don't think buying a new notebook is really worth it.

Comment: Try putting in more specifications like price range, even something you looked into so we can have a even better idea of what you want (for example something better to choose from) Asking for the GPU for the best price-performance ratio is not quite a narrow search. I MUST ADD: Laptops have other components eg. RAM, CPU etc.. for only GPU reference check  http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-...M.63761.0.html and look on the table to the right with Classes (1,2,3..) performance is descending and price can be checked on each GPU's page.

Comment: didn't know there was a specific page for Laptop GPU ranking - thx, I will look through this

Comment: there is, and there is also for CPUs: http://cpubenchmark.net/ and for GPUs (not the one I used for my search): http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the Lenovo Y50. It has a GTX 960M, which is a relatively powerful graphics card. It also has a powerful i7 processor and a 1080p screen. It is also one of the most affordable gaming laptop at around US$800.

Answer (score 1):

Asus ROG GL752VW-DH71-HID1

-£940.52
-CPU: 6th Generation "Skylake" Intel® CoreTM i7-6700HQ Quad Core Processor, 2.6-3.6 GHz
-GPU: nVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M 128bit w/ 2GB GDDR5
-RAM: 16GB 2133MHz DDR4, Hard Drive: 1TB 7200RPM HDD 
-DISPLAY: 17.3" IPS FHD Antiglare, 1920x1080

[On Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Asus-ROG-GL752VW-DH71-HID1-i7-6700HQ-2-6-3-5GHz/dp/B017LUXVFM/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1455685142&sr=8-2&keywords=asus%20rog)